# Am I allowed to do this exportation on this propositional logic statement?

Tags: logic

(A ^ B ^ C ^ (D => E)) => F

=

(A ^ B ^ C ^ D ^ E) => F

where statements are equivalent to:

A. there is an integer a

B. there is an integer b

C. there is an integer c

D. a is greater than b

E. a is greater than c

F. b is greater than c

The statement is obviously false overall, but is it valid exportation to move the implies into an and?

Comment: The two are not equivalent, but the first implies the second. For simplicity, consider $(A \land (D \to E)) \to F$ and $(A \land D \land E) \to F$ and see what happens if we assume that the second is false. This happens only when $F$ is false and all $A,D,E$ are true. But in this case also the first formula is false. Thus, we cannot have the first true and the second false, i.e. the first implies the second.

Comment: You cannot really replace the "such that" of existential quantors with "and"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm using a language that allows for proofs to be written in lisp which is why there are ands like this

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: It's not even that. $b$ and $c$ are also free in $F$, making it very ambiguous how they're actually quantified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

In general, Exportation is:

$A \to (B \to C) \Leftrightarrow (A \land B) \to C$

What does *not* hold is that

$(A \to B) \to C \Leftrightarrow (A \land B) \to C$

Counterexample:

$B$  is True, and   $A$ and $C$ are False.

Then we have $(A \to B) \to C=(F \to T) \to F = T \to F = F$, but  $(A \land B) \to C = (F \land T) \to F = F \to F = T$

So, the position of the parentheses for the conditionals really matters!

Now, you can generalize Exportation, but again, you need to have the parentheses in the right spot:

$A \to (B \to (C \to D)) \Leftrightarrow (A \land B) \to (C \to D) \Leftrightarrow (A \land B \land C) \to D$